# python 2.7 matplotlib vlines searching for sth like plt.set_data(...)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot vlines with pyplot dynamicly with python 2.7.

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = np.arange(0,100)

vl = fig.add_subplot(111)

cd = vl.vlines([],[0],[])

#plt.vlines(ax,0,1)

for i in range(0, 10000):
    #cd.set_data(ax,0,100-i)
    vl.vlines.axvline(ax,0,100 -i)   #seems like it doesnt forget the old data

    plt.pause(1e-17)

time.sleep(2)
exit()
```

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please make an effort to format your code correctly.  It'd also help if you can more clearly describe exactly what you want your code to do, and how it's going wrong.  You'll get better answers, faster, that way.

Comment: Thank you. Sry for the format, I didn't get yet. I want to plot amplitudes of a fft. So I will edit the time signal every second and plot the fft result with the vlines in matplotlib. But I cannot refresh my data using vlines. It is all good with the normal plot function. But I want to use vlines because the look better to me. The code I've posted is just test. vlines just adds new data but doesnt remove the old one.

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw an `axvline` then on the next iteration of the loop, delete the old line and draw a new one?

Answer (score -2):

ok now I use namesubplotFigure.cla() and after that I just redo namesubplotFigure.vlines(...). Its optic result is ok but the ylim and ylim are deleted as well.

Comment: Instead of answering your own question with a suboptimal solution, you may rather update your question such that it contains a useful problem description. What is the problem with the code you have, how should it look like instead? If being asked for clarification in the comments, respond to such comments, by adding the requested information in the quesiton. See also [ask].